# Nonsensical dotnet build error: Package ...Contract 4.0.3 is not compatible with net8.0. Package ...Contract 4.0.3 supports: net8.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget

Build error

> Error NU1202 : Package Components.Services.Client.Contract 4.0.3 is not compatible with net8.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0). Package Components.Services.Client.Contract 4.0.3 supports: net8.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0)

This seems to say be saying that the package in question is not compatible with net8.0, instead it's compatible with... net8.0?

What am I missing here?  How can I deal with this nonsense?

Comment: Do you have a [mre] we can play with?

Comment: No, sorry, this is in a very large (280+) project .sln.  I am dealing with a client's time here, so I can't spend it on trying to create a minimal reproducible example.  I was a ble to "solve" this problem by some combination of:  removing/re-adding all PackageReferences in the effected project, clearing my nuget cache & rebooting my machine.  I would still like to understand how to make sense of this error, though.  What does it mean?  How should I interpret this error?

Comment: it looks like a bug in nuget, but until we have a reproducible example, we can't debug nuget's code to figure out why this happens. I've seen customers report this problem a few times, but nobody has ever provided a sample project to reproduce it, unfortunately.

Comment: Is Components.Services.Client.Contract nuget package from third party or something that you have control over or is it just .csproj referenced in some executable ?